# Order nodes in adjacency matrix

Tags: adjacency-matrix, adjacency-list

I am trying to read adjacency lists and put the nodes in a fixed order such that the matrices can be visualized for comparison. So far, I have used Python's NetworkX to read the adjacency list, but have not found a way to sort the nodes yet. Anybody has any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more googling and research, I found this link that answered my question. All credits go to the author of the post:

http://sociograph.blogspot.com/2012/11/visualizing-adjacency-matrices-in-python.html